# SQL query finding best categories match

Tags: mysql, sql

I have categories and multiple categorization for my Items. **How to find, for specific Item, other Items that have same categories, ordered by most categories matching (aka best match)?**

My table structure is roughly:

**Item Table**

```
ID
Name
...
```

**Category Table**

```
ID
Name
...
```

**Categorization Table**

```
ID
Item_ID
Category_ID
...
```

To find all Items having similar categories, for example, I use

```
SELECT `items`.* 
FROM `items` 
INNER JOIN `categorizations` c1
ON c1.`item_id` = `items`.`id`
INNER JOIN `categorizations` c2
ON c2.`item_id` = <Item_ID>
WHERE `c1.`category_id` = c2.`category_id`
```

Comment: So what is your question? What have you tried? Why did that not work?

Comment: Thank you, rephrased and marked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should produce a table of counts of category matches between each pair of items that share at least one category.

```
select i1.item_id,i2.item_id,count(1)
from items i1
join categorizations c1 on c1.item_id=i1.item_id
join categorizations c2 on c2.category_id=c1.category_id
join items i2 on c2.item_id=i2.item_id
where i1.item_id <> i2.item_id
group by i1.item_id,i2.item_id
order by count(1)
```

I suspect that it may be a bit slow, though. I don't have an instance of MySQL at the moment to try it out.

Comment: It does exactly what I need, adding to WHERE clause  i1.id = <Item_ID>, as I want to find best matching items for specific item. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
select item_id, count(id)
from item_category ic
where exists( 
 select category_id 
 from item_category ic2 
 where ic2.item_id = @item_id 
 and ic2.category_id = ic.category_id ) 
where item_id <> @item_id
group by item_id
order by count(item_id) desc
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative method which I have just implemented to solve this problem is using bitwise operators to speed things up. In MySQL this method only works if you have 64 or less categories as the bit functions are 64 bit.

1) Assign each category a unique integer value which is a power of 2.

2) For each item sum the category values that the item is in to create a 64 bit int representing all of the categories that the item is in.

3) To compare an item to another do something like:

```
SELECT id, BIT_COUNT(item1categories & item2categories) AS numMatchedCats FROM tablename HAVING numMatchedCats > 0 ORDER BY numMatchedCats DESC
```

The BIT_COUNT() function might be MySQL specific so an alternative may well be required for any other DB.

MySQL bit functions used are explained here:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/bit-functions.html